# Getting bitmap data from JPEG image using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, image

I need to extract the raw RGB bitmap data from a JPEG or PNG file, with all the bits in the file, not a window or color converted version.

I'm new to Cocoa, but it looks like I open an image using NSImage like this:

```
NSString* imageName=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"/Users/me/Temp/oxberry.jpg" ofType:@"JPG"];
NSImage*  tempImage=[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep=[[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[tempImage TIFFRepresentation]] autorelease];
unsigned char* bytes=[imageRep bitmapData];
int bits=[imageRep bitsPerPixel];
```

Then to get the bitmap data there seems to be lots of options: Bitmapimage, CGImage, etc.

What is the simplest approach and if there was a code snippet, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  As you noticed, there are lot of ways to do this.

Once you have an NSImage, you can create a bitmap representation, and access its bytes directly. An easy way to get a NSBitmapImageRep is to do this:

```
NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[tempImage TIFFRepresentation]] autorelease];

unsigned char* bytes = [imageRep bitmapData];
int bitsPerPixel  = [imageRep bitsPerPixel];
// etc
```

Going through the TIFFRepresentation step is safer than accessing the NSImage's representations directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but for some reason, either the image is not getting loaded, or the BitmapImageRep is not working, as I get 0 for the bitsPerPixel. How can I see if the image loaded (Sorry as I'm very new on my Cocoa legs). I edited the code in my original post to reflect the changes

Comment: I figured out how to verify it, but still can't seem to load the image. The file exists in that folder.

Comment: if you step through the code in the debugger, you should be able to see what's failing.  If it doesn't load the image, tempImage will be nil., etc. The debugger is your friend.

Comment: Instead of NSString* imageName=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"/Users/me/Temp/oxberry.jpg" ofType:@"JPG"];
you should be doing NSString* imageName=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"oxberry" ofType:@"jpg"]; where oxberry.jpg is a file you include in your project.  If you want to just include a file from a specific place on your disk, you don't need the pathForResource stuff at all.